# OOP Inheritance Extends

Tags: java, inheritance, overriding, abstract

Only run with one abstract in the **Get Phase**. I really don't know why, OMG?

```
abstract public class Vehicle {
    public int nWheels = 0;
    public int VCapacity;

    // Set
    public void numWheels(int nWheels) {
        this.nWheels = nWheels;
    }
    public void VCapacity(int VCapacity) {
        this.VCapacity = VCapacity;
    }

    // Get
    public abstract int getWheels();
    public abstract int VCapacity();

    public Vehicle() { }

    public Vehicle(int nWheels, int VCapacity) {
        numWheels(nWheels);
        VCapacity(VCapacity);
    }
}
```

Not running it says:

> Bus is not abstract and does not override abstract method VCapacity() in Vehicle
>   public class Bus extends Vehicle

Comment: You should standardize your instance variable names to be simpler, but more descriptive e.g. `wheelCount` and `capacity`. Prefixing your variables with a capital `V` is not only unnecessary (because the object *is a* Vehicle, but it breaks JavaBean spec (Starting an instance variable with a capital letter).

Comment: Is that so, so start with a small letter okey Thanks bro :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you extends `abstract` class you need to override the method defined in the parent class.

```
public class Bus extends Vehicle {
    public Bus() {
        super(6, 4); // to set capacity use the Vehicle (int nWheels, int VCapacity) constructor
    }

    @Override
    public int VCapacity() {
    }
}
```

In `Vehicle` it doesn't receive parameters.

Comment: `public int getWheels() {
  return this.nWheels;
 }
 
  @Override
    public int VCapacity();
    
 public Bus () 
 {
  super (6);
   
 } `

Comment: How do i add the Capacity in the Codes?

Comment: @CharlesJacob to set capacity use the `Vehicle (int nWheels, int VCapacity)` constructor, `public Bus () { super (6, 4); }`

Comment: YOURE AWESOME MAN HAHAHAH THANKYOUSOMUCH HAHAH ♥ i wish u can help me in my Array in Java teacher sucks anyw Thankyousomuch Godbless Sir

Comment: @CharlesJacob Post a new question with the code you are having troubles with and what is the problem.

Comment: its on my laptop and its really hard to explain can i like add u on FB really need some one like u or ill just Tag u when i posted the question Thanks Might Guy ♥

Comment: @CharlesJacob It will be best if you tag me when you post the question.

Comment: Yes Guy :) Thanks for your big help

Comment: do you know where i can study Array Online?  those easy to understand with explanation u know

Comment: can u pls help me in my new Question Thankyou

Comment: Guy http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41724220/singly-linked-list-search